# debug ros node python

Tags: ros, python, ide

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am new to ROS

how do you debug your ros node, say you code it in python.

Is it possible to use run a ros node in an ide and set break points ect?
I saw a link on setting up ide's but they seemed like it was for C++ IDE's

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54602/debug-ros-node-python/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From commandline, you can run your script on debugger by:

```
$ roscd %YOUR_PKG_HOME%
$ gdb python
$ run %YOUR_SCRIPT_PATH%
```

If you'd prefer to sticking to `eclipse`, one dumb workaround to utilize `make` solution on wiki is:

1 Install `pydev` on eclipse, create your `python` project on eclipse by "File" --> "New" --> "Pydev Project". When successful, close eclipse.

2 Copy the `.project` file that was just generated by eclipse. Eg. by doing:

```
$ roscd %YOUR_PKG_HOME%
$ cp .project .project.org
```

3 Run `make eclipse-project` following http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs#Eclipse. If you don't have `Makefile` in the current dir, create one as the same wiki page suggests when error occurs.

4 Swap .project and remove .cproject:

```
$ mv .project.org .project 
$ rm .cproject
```

This sets up ROS python environment on eclipse. You should be able to run your ROS script in debug mode.

Apparently this is not smart and ideal, but works for me.

This works even on Groovy where `make eclipse-project` generates many unnecessary files & directories. In this case you might want to remove them & `Makefile` you no longer need by like:

```
$ rm -fR catkin* CATKIN_IGNORE cmake_install.cmake devel/ gtest/ Makefile test_results/
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2014-01-14**:
Hi Thanks for the reply
I also got this to work for python debugging
http://winpdb.org/docs/ Its a graphical debugger for python. All I have to do is go the source directory and run it from the terminal from there.